# Convert Minutes to Hours using JodaTime

Tags: java

I'm having Minutes in `java.lang.Long` and want to convert this value to `java.math.BigDecimal`, ie. as Hours.

```
BigDecimal hours = BigDecimal.valueOf(minutes)  
                             .divide(BigDecimal.valueOf(DateTimeConstants.MINUTES_PER_HOUR))
                             .setScale(2,RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
```

Tried the above method. It return `hours`, but no the way actually i want it

**How i need is :**

```
240 Minutes : 4 Hours
230 Minutes : 3.50 hours
```

Any help?

Comment: 230 minutes is not 3.5 hours for Joda. May be you need separate out hours and calculate the rest o minutes and concatenate it into a string.

Comment: @DhanushGopinath Duration duration = Duration.standardMinutes(230);
Period period = new Period(duration); 
`System.out.println(period.get(DurationFieldType.hours())+period.get(DurationFieldType.minutes()));` 
When u try the above you will get `3.50` in `jodatime`

Comment: What does this have to do with joda time?

Comment: Why jodaTime when you could do simple arithmetic in java?

Comment: Remove irrelevant tags.

Comment: Please choose an answer to close off the question

Answer (score 1):

I would convert your Minutes to a Period object:

```
Minutes minutes = ...;
Long millisec = minutes*60*1000;
Period period = new Period(millisec);
```

Then use the Period object you can ask the Hours. Anything you want...

Answer (score 1):

Note: 230 minutes is not 3.50 hours, it's 3.83 hours, i'm assuming you mean "3 hours and 50 minutes".

So what you want is the hh:mm representation.

You don't need BigDecimals. Use this:

```
    long minutes = 230;
    long hours = minutes / 60;
    long minnutesRemaining = minutes % 60;

    System.out.println(hours + "." + minnutesRemaining);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm betting the OP actually wants to convert minutes into hours and minutes. This is as easy as:

```
int minutes = 230;
System.out.println(
    String.format("%d Minutes: %d:%02d Hours", minutes, (minutes/60), (minutes%60)));
```

Just printing the minutes divided by 60 (using integer arithmetic) and the modulo of minutes divided by 60 (formatted as two digits with leading zeros by the "%02d" format.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `BigDecimal` easy. You can use [divideAndRemainder()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29)

```
long minutes = 230L;
BigDecimal min = new BigDecimal(minutes);
BigDecimal constant = new BigDecimal(60);
BigDecimal[] val=min.divideAndRemainder(constant);
System.out.println(val[0]+"."+val[1]+" Hours");
```

Out put:

```
3.50 Hours
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in what universe 230 minutes equals 3.5 hours, so I'm afraid that some string manipulation is your best bet:

```
BigDecimal hours = new BigDecimal(
        String.format("%d.%d", minutes / 60, minutes % 60));
```

Printing out the value of `hours` yields `3.50`, as per your requirement.

Comment: You can use `divideAndRemainder()` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#divideAndRemainder%28java.math.BigDecimal%29

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera Which is better in exactly what way?

Comment: Read the provided link. It says it is faster

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera It's faster than carrying out both BigDecimal operations separately, but is it also faster than carrying out the two primitive arithmetic operations separately?

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I've tested the performance of both the primitive arithmetic solution and the `divideAndRemainder()` solution, and for an input value of `230`, the `divideAndRemainder()` solution is about 2.7 times slower on my Oracle Java 7 JVM.

Answer (score 0):

Use integer and modulo arithmetic:

`long hours = minutes / 60; /*implicit round-down*/`

`long numberAfterDecimal = (minutes % 1.0 /*pull out the remainder*/) * 60;`

Then format these two numbers as you wish.